# Do structures count as terrain?

Tags: league-of-legends

Vayne's Condemn says:

> **If they collide with terrain** after being knocked back, they are dealt the same amount of physical damage again and are stunned for 1.5 seconds.

Similarly, Poppy's Heroic Charge says:

> ... **if they collide with terrain**, her target will take a high amount of magic damage and be stunned for 1.5 seconds.

So if the enemy hits a turret, inhibitor, or nexus, does it count as terrain and cause these abilities to stun the target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Turrets count as terrain for the purpose of champion abilities.

The [wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret#Notes) confirms this:

> Towers count as terrain. Any abilities that interacts with terrain
>   will trigger the effect, namely  Poppy's  Heroic Charge's and  Vayne's
>   Condemn's stuns.

Comment: I was looking under the skills themselves... :/

Comment: What about inhibitors and nexuses?...nexi?...nexussssssss...now they all sound weird...

Comment: @OrigamiRobot same deal.

Comment: For the record, this also includes destroyed buildings. The base is still there and counts as impassable terrain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they count as terrain. They even count when destroyed. So do things like trundle's pillar. It can be very powerful for trundle to cause a pillar to appear behind the target, then for vayne to shoot him.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I haven't ever seen that particular interaction.

Comment: other then from my personnal experience no

Comment: It was my understanding the terrain from trundle, annivia, and jarvan IV were all fake "minions" which is why a lot of skills go through them. It would surprise me if you can stun into them.